# Java won't recognize a double when I'm trying to make a calculation

Tags: java

So for this program I have to use java GUI to take in temperature and wind speed, and from there I calculate the Windchill. I have it so that when the user clicks the "Calculate windchill" button, it should use the formula I entered to calculate this. But I keep getting various errors surrounding this double, and I am not sure why. You can find the error in the actionPerformed section, it's the "windChillInt" that is getting this error. Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Windchill extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 200;
    private static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 150;
    private static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 250;
    private String degree;
    private String wind;
    private int degreeInt;
    private int windInt;
    private double windChillInt;
    private JButton windButton;
    private JLabel prompt;
    private JLabel prompt1;
    private JTextField inputLine;
    private JTextField inputLine1;

    public Windchill(){
        setTitle("Windchill");
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setLocation(FRAME_X_ORIGIN, FRAME_Y_ORIGIN);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());    
        inputLine = new JTextField();
        inputLine.setColumns(3);
        inputLine.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(inputLine);
        prompt = new JLabel();
        prompt.setText("Enter the degrees in Farienheight       ");
        prompt.setSize(150,25);
        contentPane.add(prompt);
        inputLine1 = new JTextField();
        inputLine1.setColumns(3);
        inputLine1.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(inputLine1);

        prompt1 = new JLabel();
        prompt1.setText("Enter the wind speed in MPH");
        prompt1.setSize(150,25);
        contentPane.add(prompt1);

        windButton = new JButton("Calculate windchill");
        contentPane.add(windButton);
        windButton.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if (event.getSource() instanceof JButton){
            JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
            if (clickedButton == windButton){
                degree = inputLine.getText();
                degreeInt = Integer.parseInt(degree);
                wind = inputLine1.getText();
                windInt = Integer.parseInt(wind);
                windChillInt = 0.08(degreeInt - 91.4)        (3.71*math.sqrt(windInt) + 5.81 - 0.25 *windInt) + 91.4;

            }

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Windchill frame;
        frame = new Windchill();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Okay thanks guys i got that to work but now I have another problem, it wont display the new windChillInt on the GUI like I want it to. here is what i changed it to.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if (event.getSource() instanceof JButton){
            JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
            if (clickedButton == windButton){
                degree = inputLine.getText();
                degreeInt = Integer.parseInt(degree);
                wind = inputLine1.getText();
                windInt = Integer.parseInt(wind);
                windChillInt = 0.08 * (degreeInt - 91.4)*(3.71* (Math.sqrt(windInt)) + 5.81 - 0.25 *windInt) + 91.4;

                prompt2 = new JLabel();
                prompt2.setText("The windchill is " + windChillInt);
                prompt2.setSize(150,25);
                Container contentPane = getContentPane();
                contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                contentPane.add(prompt2);
            }
```

Comment: You want to post the error messages, don't you? And also indicate with comments which lines cause them. You don't want to make us guess, right?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with this line:

```
windChillInt = 0.08(degreeInt - 91.4)        (3.71 * math.sqrt(windInt) + 5.81 - 0.25 *windInt) + 91.4;
```

---

`windChillInt = 0.08(degreeInt - 91.4)` should be `windChillInt = 0.08 * (degreeInt - 91.4)`.

Then, you either need to multiply `windChillInt = 0.08 * (degreeInt - 91.4)` and `(3.71 * math.sqrt(windInt) + 5.81 - 0.25 *windInt) + 91.4` together, or move `(3.71 * math.sqrt(windInt) + 5.81 - 0.25 *windInt) + 91.4` down to its own statement and assign it to something.

Answer (score 1):

Put the operator between two expression.

For ex

```
result = exp1 operator exp2
```

In your case

```
windChillInt = 0.08 * (degreeInt - 91.4) * (3.71*math.sqrt(windInt) + 5.81 - 0.25 *windInt) + 91.4;
```

Comment: Okay thanks guys, it works now but now Im having the issue that it wont show this value on the GUI when I want it to. Here is what I have

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error:  `0.08(degreeInt - 91.4)`.  Are you missing a multiply operator?

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering you haven't posted the error message, I'm assuming the problem is a Syntax Error, something about an `unexpected token '('`, probably?  I haven't tried compiling and running it, but based on the code the issue seems to be that you're multiplying `0.08` by `degreeInt - 91.4` by simply writing it next to it, and doing the same thing again with the two parenthesized expressions.

Conceptually, this is fine, but an unfortunate truth is that most programming languages are not math.  Even if you're used to writing equations that use expressions like `2x` all day long, in the world of Java, C, C++, Python, Ruby, or really any other language you can think of (except Mathematica, which is designed to support syntax that mirrors mathematical notation), you'll have to write `2 * x` instead.

I'd replace

```
windChillInt = 0.08(degreeInt - 91.4)        (3.71*math.sqrt(windInt) + 5.81 - 0.25 *windInt) + 91.4;`
```

with

```
windChillInt = 0.08 * (degreeInt - 91.4) * (3.71 * math.sqrt(windInt) + 5.81 - 0.25 * windInt) + 91.4;
```

I've also cleaned up some of your formatting a bit.  When you're just starting out, things like

```
0.25 *windInt
```

are fine, but as your code base grows larger and larger you'll want to be able to quickly glance at any of your code without being momentarily confused by how it's written.  Pick some formatting conventions you like, and stick to them.  Either *always* write `x*y`, or *always* write `x * y`, but not both, and stay far away from `x *y`, `x* y`, or anything else along those lines.  I also notice you added a tab in the middle of your line, probably because it looked like a space with the indentation settings you were using.  Not too big a deal, but a little weird.

Also, I know this is your first question on stack overflow, so I don't want to be too harsh, but next time try to focus on just the code that's causing the problem, and if people need more information, supply the rest of the code.  Don't just give them a wall of text and ask them to root around in it for the bug.  Moreover, error messages are really helpful to people trying to diagnose an issue, so consider posting that next time as well.

Finally, I see a bunch of numerical constants in your code.  I don't know much about the math behind windchill, so I'm not sure if it would ever make sense to change these to other values, but in general it's a good idea to take any constants that could change in your code and put them in a variable somewhere.

What do I mean by "constants that can change?  Aren't constants, by definintion, constant?"  Sometimes, there are certain numbers that, if you modified them, would still make sense.  For example, if you're writing a game an include the force of gravity on earth in a calculation

```
// assuming yVelocity is in meters/second
yVelocity = yVelocity - 9.8 * timeElapsedThisFrame;
```

you now have a problem, because if you ever want to change the game to have a level set on mars, you have to hunt down where you specify the gravity and add something like this

```
if (planet == EARTH) {
    yVelocity = yVelocity - 9.8 * timeElapsedThisFrame;
} else if (planet == MARS) {
    yVelocity = yVelocity - /* whatever the gravity is on mars */ * timeElapsedThisFrame;
}
```

this quickly becomes extremely unwieldy and hard to maintain, and a much better solution is just to replace the gravity constant with a variable from the outset

```
// at the top of your class:
double forceOfGravity = 9.8;
// in your "move" method:
yVelocity = yVelocity - forceOfGravity * timeElapsedThisFrame;
```

and if you ever want to change gravity, it's extremely simple.  This is an example of a constant that can change.

I'd recommend doing the same for `0.08`, `91.4`, `3.71`, `5.81`, `0.25`, and `91.4`.  I don't know what any of these numbers are, but maybe some of them have to do with air pressure, in which case your app won't work on mount everest, or maybe they have to do with human body temperature, in which case your app won't work for cats.  I don't know much about the problem domain, but these practices are always a good idea.  Also, they make the code more readable, because the names of constants describe what they do.

Anyway, you're new, you're learning, and that's great!  Happy coding!